# How would I extract a region of some NEMO ocean model output in Iris?

Tags: python-iris

Is there a straightforward way to extract a region from an Iris cube which is described by 2D latitude and longitude variables, for example using NEMO ocean model data?

I found [this](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/12/29/iris_ocean_models/) workaround but was wondering if there was a way to do this in 'pure' Iris, without having to resort to defining a new function?

For example, if I have this cube...

```
In [30]: print(cube)
mole_concentration_of_dimethyl_sulfide_in_sea_water / (mol m-3) (time: 780; cell index along second dimension: 330; cell index along first dimension: 360)
     Dimension coordinates:
          time                                                       x                                       -                                      -
          cell index along second dimension                          -                                       x                                      -
          cell index along first dimension                           -                                       -                                      x
     Auxiliary coordinates:
          latitude                                                   -                                       x                                      x
          longitude                                                  -                                       x                                      x
```

... and then try to extract a region using [intersection](https://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/v1.9.0/html/iris/iris/cube.html), I get this...

```
>>> subset = cube.intersection(longitude=(-10, 10))

CoordinateMultiDimError: Multi-dimensional coordinate not supported: 'longitude'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the error messsage, iris does not currently support subsetting by multi-dimensional coordinates, so you *have* to write a function similar to `bbox_extract_2Dcoords()` in that blog post. All it does is creates a boolean mask with values set to `True` within your region of interest and `False` outside. Then the boundaries of this region are used as indices to subset the cube.

An alternative would be to regrid the data to a regular grid defined by 1D longitude and latitude and then subset the data using the standard `Constraint()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Could this regridding to 1D longitude and latitude within Iris?

Comment: @jonnyhtw yes, it should be possible with using https://scitools-docs.github.io/iris/master/generated/api/iris/experimental/regrid.html#iris.experimental.regrid.regrid_weighted_curvilinear_to_rectilinear